# Perl DBI DBD::mysql get the databases name from mysql server

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I have a production server that creates different databases everyday in a MySql
server.

i need to write a `perl script` that would run at the end of the day
and do the following.

connect to the mysql server and get the list of all the names of the databases
it has. then connect to each of them and check the data that was stored.

the only thing i wasn't able to do with `DBI and DBD::mysql`
was read the database names from the mysql server.

i wasn't able to find any DBI function that would work without connecting to a 
database first.

any help/example/URL would be very helpful :-)

Comment: In Sybase, there's a standard "master" database where info like that is stored. E.g. for your purpose `master..sysdatabases`. Not sure about MySql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
use DBI;
use strict;
use warnings;
my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:information_schema', $ENV{'USER'}, $ENV{'PASSWD'}, { 'RaiseError' => 1 } );
my $databases = $dbh->selectcol_arrayref('show databases');

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $databases;
__END__
$VAR1 = [
      'information_schema',
      'mysql',
      'your_database_1',
      'your_database_2'
    ];
```

Only databases authorized to the user you connect with will be shown.

Comment: THANK YOU :-) that worked , i have added it to my code and it works like a charm :-) thank you again.

Answer (score 4):

Try using [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html) database - that database name always exists and thus can be hard-coded into DBI.

To be [more specific](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/schemata-table.html), the equivalent to `SHOW DATABASES` is:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME AS `Database`
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
```